# How to store an int array values in a char array?

Tags: c

I have an integer array:

```
int a[4] = {192,168,8,100};
```

I need to store these numbers in a char array like follows:

```
char ip[15] = "192.168.8.100";
```

Is there any library functions in C to use?

Comment: `sprintf(ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])` should suffice.

Comment: Also `char ip[15]` --> `char ip[16]`

Comment: Thanks. It's simple. :)

Comment: Probably not strictly necessary here, but you should use `snprintf()` rather than `sprintf()` to prevent any possibility of a buffer overrun. Always bounds-check in C. Code defensively!

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to be on the heap and dynamically allocate memory you can use the [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html).

```
char *ip = NULL;
int ret;
ret = asprintf(&ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
if (ret < 0)
{  
 // error handling
}
// use ip
free(ip); 
ip = NULL;
```

Otherwise, if you know the size before hand you can use [sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

```
sprintf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```

Personally, I prefer to use `asprintf`, however, you need to remember to free that memory allocated by `asprintf` otherwise you will get a memory leak.

Side note, `asprintf` calls realloc internally so you could use it for string concatenation as long as you free successive calls.

Comment: `asprintf` is not standard.

Comment: Line 3 in your first block should instead be `ret = asprintf(&ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);`

Answer (score 0):

You always, *always*, ***always*** check that you aren’t overrunning your buffer in C, and especially when you’re dealing with data you got over a network.

For example, you set the array to fifteen characters, but the string `"100.100.100.100"` has **sixteen** with its terminating null.  That works for now, but is precariously brittle.  Or you might get buggy or malicious input like `{-1000000000L, -1000000000L, -1000000000L, -1000000000}`.  Or you might later refactor to support IPv6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DOTTED_IPV4_LEN     16U

int main(void)
{
  static const unsigned char a[4] = {192,168,8,100};
  char ip[DOTTED_IPV4_LEN];

  snprintf( ip, DOTTED_IPV4_LEN, "%u.%u.%u.%u", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] );
  puts(ip);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In fact, some shops, including I think Microsoft, wouldn’t even accept the destination buffer being declared on the stack like that and would demand the extra precaution of making `ip` a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory, perhaps:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DOTTED_IPV4_LEN     16U

int main(void)
{
  static const unsigned char a[4] = {192,168,8,100};
  char (* const ip)[DOTTED_IPV4_LEN] = malloc(sizeof(*ip));

  assert(ip);
  snprintf( *ip, sizeof(*ip), "%u.%u.%u.%u", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] );
  puts(*ip);

  free(ip); // Unnecessary because we're about to quit.
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```